# How to import XML File containing Chinese Characters and UTF-8 Encoded to Oracle Database using US7ASCII

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, utf-8, ascii

I have been struggling to import XML File that contains Chinese Characters and  encoded in UTF-8 from external parties to our Oracle Database, which is using US7ASCII encode. However, the error below keeps on prompting:

```
pkg_dxe.get_xmldata: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00200: could not convert from encoding UTF-8 to US-ASCII
Error at line 1
```

The PL\SQL Code that handle the import process:

```
v_xml := XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR_IBISAPP', 'xmldata.xml'), nls_charset_id('UTF8'));
Select count(*) into v_cnt from XML_TAB_A;
If v_cnt > 0 then    
    update XML_TAB_A set 
        xml_data = v_xml, 
        timestamp = sysdate;
else
    Insert into XML_TAB_A(xml_data, timestamp) values (v_xml, sysdate);
end if;
```

Sample of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
<APPLICATION>
  <DXE_APPLICATION>
    <APP_TRAN_NO>20180621031622817</APP_TRAN_NO> 
  </DXE_APPLICATION>
  <DXE_CUSTOMER>
    <APP_TRAN_NO>20180621031622817</APP_TRAN_NO> 
    <SEQ>0</SEQ>  
    <CUST_TITLE>Mr.</CUST_TITLE> 
    <CUST_NAME>HELLO</CUST_NAME> 
    <CUST_GNAME>HELLO</CUST_GNAME> 
    <CUST_ONAME>hello</CUST_ONAME> 
    <CUST_NAME_CHN>陳大文</CUST_NAME_CHN>
  </DXE_CUSTOMER>
</APPLICATION>
```

The field that is responsible with the error is Cust_Name_Chn, yet we cannot exclude that Chinese Characters will be provided in other fields as well.

Is there any way to properly import the XML to our Oracle Database without prompting error when it contains Chinese Characters? It is acceptable if the Chinese Characters cannot be read after import in this phase.

I have tried using the CONVERT() function, but the error LPX-00200 still persist.

Comment: You should use `nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')`. Oracle character set `UTF8` is [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8). For Chinese characters this could be relevant because you may use characters outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider to migrate your database to UTF-8, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011). Migrating a DB from `US7ASCII` to `AL32UTF8` should not create any trouble.

[Oracle XML DB Restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/appjspec.htm#ADXDB3700) says:

> NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, and NCLOB Not Supported – Oracle XML DB does not
>   support the use of SQL data types NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, and NCLOB for any
>   of the following:
>
> - Mapping XML elements or attributes to these data types using the SQLType annotation in an XML schema
> - Generating XML data from these data types using SQL/XML functions XMLElement, XMLAttributes, and XMLForest
> - Within SQL/XML functions XMLQuery and XMLTable, using XQuery functions ora:view (deprecated), fn:doc, and fn:collection on tables
>     that contain columns with these data types
>
> To handle, store, or generate XML data that contains multibyte
>   characters, Oracle strongly recommends that you use AL32UTF8 as the
>   database character set.

You could store plain data as `NCLOB`:

```
CREATE TABLE XML_TAB_A (xml_data NCLOB, ts TIMESTAMP);

DECLARE

    v_nclob NCLOB;
    v_cnt NUMBER;

    xbfile   BFILE; 
    destOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    srcOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    langContext INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX; 
    warning INTEGER; 

BEGIN

    xbfile := BFILENAME ('XMLDIR_IBISAPP', 'xmldata.xml'); 
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN (xbfile); 
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY (v_nclob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION); 
    DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE (
        dest_lob => v_nclob, 
        src_bfile => xbfile, 
        amount => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(xbfile), 
        dest_offset => destOffset, 
        src_offset => srcOffset, 
        bfile_csid => NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'), 
        lang_context => langContext, 
        warning => warning);    
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE (xbfile); 

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_cnt FROM XML_TAB_A;
    IF v_cnt > 0 THEN    
         UPDATE XML_TAB_A SET 
              xml_data = v_nclob, 
              ts = SYSDATE;
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO XML_TAB_A(xml_data, ts) VALUES (v_nclob, SYSDATE);
    END IF;

END;
```

However, then you cannot use any of the [XMLTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm) functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have found a solution very similar to yours, but to read the XML file into Clob, then use a function to convert it back to XMLTYPE, and Chinese characters will be transformed to ??? without prompting error

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a US7ASCII database to test with, but you can convert character sets for xmltypes through the getblobval method

```
with x as
    (select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
<APPLICATION>
  <DXE_APPLICATION>
    <APP_TRAN_NO>20180621031622817</APP_TRAN_NO> 
  </DXE_APPLICATION>
  <DXE_CUSTOMER>
    <APP_TRAN_NO>20180621031622817</APP_TRAN_NO> 
    <SEQ>0</SEQ>  
    <CUST_TITLE>Mr.</CUST_TITLE> 
    <CUST_NAME>HELLO</CUST_NAME> 
    <CUST_GNAME>HELLO</CUST_GNAME> 
    <CUST_ONAME>hello</CUST_ONAME> 
    <CUST_NAME_CHN>陳大文</CUST_NAME_CHN>
  </DXE_CUSTOMER>
</APPLICATION>') a from dual)
select xmltype(x.a.getblobval(NLS_CHARSET_ID('US7ASCII')),NLS_CHARSET_ID('US7ASCII')) y
from x x;
```

Turned the name line to :

```
<CUST_NAME_CHN>&#x9673;&#x5927;&#x6587;</CUST_NAME_CHN>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I implement the getblobval method into my code? As I am directly reading the XML data from the directory file with the code below:
    v_xml := XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR_IBISAPP', 'xmldata.xml'), nls_charset_id('UTF8'));

Comment: I don't think this will work, because `GETBLOBVAL()` is a member function of `XMLTYPE`. In given conditions it is not possible to create a `XMLTYPE` instance where you could apply `GETBLOBVAL()`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to read the XML file into Clob, and then convert it back to XMLType to avoid prompting encoding error

```
file := bfilename('XMLDIR_IBISAPP', 'xmldata.xml');
dbms_lob.createTemporary(contents, true, dbms_lob.session);
dbms_lob.fileopen(file, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
dbms_lob.loadClobfromFile(contents, file, dbms_lob.getLength(file), dest_offset, src_offset, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'), lang_context, conv_warning);
dbms_lob.fileclose(file);

v_xml := XMLTYPE.createXML(contents);

Update xml_tab_a set 
        xml_data = v_xml, 
        timestamp = sysdate;
```

Comment: This will convert `<CUST_NAME_CHN>陳大文</CUST_NAME_CHN>` to `<CUST_NAME_CHN>???</CUST_NAME_CHN>` - is this your intention?

Comment: Yes. That will be fine in this phase as long as error is avoided

Comment: Transforming our database to use Unicode is not possible as we have some subsystems that rely on the current environment to function. As we currently only have 1 data field that contain Chinese Characters, it seems it is the temporary solution. Is there any possible way to be able to read the Chinese Characters in US7ASCII database? Thanks.

Comment: The database has **two** character sets. The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` (which is `US7ASCII ` in your case) and the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` which typically supports all Unicode characters. `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is used for `CLOB`, `VARCHAR2` and also for `XMLTYPE` - there you cannot story any Chinese Character! However, you can use `NCLOB`, `NVARCHAR2` which uses `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` and is able to handle any character. That's the solution I provided as answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have never though of that. I will try to edit my code in this approach. Thanks very much for your help.